# UML Activity Diagram :loop on decision node

Tags: loops, uml, activity-diagram, visual-paradigm, uml-decision-node

I am learning UML and I would like to know if it is possible to loop on the decision node. 
Because in my cockburn I have :

3-Enter with ticket
3a1-Enter with card
3a2-Failure: return to 1

If it is possible, how can I do it with Visual Paradigm?
Thanks!
[image]

Comment: What does "return to 1" mean?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that in UML. A decision node is just for evaluation of a condition previously set in an action.

From your scenario it's not obvious how you want to establish a loop anyway. I would guess that the case "none selected" needs to be modeled. Just make your action above not deliver anything else but the ticket/card conditions.

Comment: What do you mean by "Just make your action above not deliver anything else but the ticket/card conditions."?Thank you

Comment: The action above the decision is something like "ask for payment procedure" (I guess). And that will only continue after a choice is made. This choice is then evaluated in the decision node. That's the whole purpose of a decision node. It's not an action itself.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're asking if it's possible to loop from a decision back to itself. Doing so would create an infinite loop. The reason is that the guard condition would never have a chance to change, so the token would cycle forever.

Comment: Why wouldn't it have a chance to change? There can be an action that changes the condition, no?

Comment: If you add another action, you no longer have a loop from a decision back to itself!